# Rational functions on $\mathbb{P}^1$ without poles

Tags: algebraic-geometry

my question is related to [this exposition](http://www.ams.org/notices/200301/what-is.pdf) about Shtukas.
In the subsection on Algebraic Geometry, D.Goss is talking about "rational functions without poles on $\mathbb{P}^1$".
**I have the following questions:**

$\bullet$ What does $\Gamma$ denote? Is this just the restriction of the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}$ to the open affine subspace $U$?

$\bullet$ What does he mean by a rational function without poles? How is a pole defined in this context in the first place?

Thank You for Your help,
SDIGR

Comment: The function field is $k(X)= Frac(k[X])$, the rational functions in $k(X)$ have zeros/poles at $X = a, a \in \overline{k}$ or at $X=  \infty$ (that is $f(1/X)$ has a pole at $X=0$) then $O_{\Bbb{P}^1}(U)$ is the subring of rational functions with no poles on $U$, from $O_{\Bbb{P}^1}(\overline{k}) = k[X]$ we obtain that $O_{\Bbb{P}^1}(\overline{k} \cup \infty) = k$. Then the goal is to formalize those things in term of sheafs and $\Bbb{P}^1=\{ [a:b]\}$ and to extend to other curves.

Comment: Hello reuns. So You say "The rational functions in k(X) have zeros/poles at $X=a,a\in \overline{k}$." I guess this means "$f(X)=\frac{u(X)}{v(X)}$ has a zero/pole at $X=a,a\in \overline{k}$ iff $u(a)=0/v(a)=0$". This makes sense. Stupid Question:What do You mean by "No poles on $U$?" Does this mean $f\in k(X)\colon f \not \equiv 0 \pmod{\mathfrak{p}}$ for all $\mathfrak{p}\in U$?.

Comment: Could You give me a Definition to work with? What does it mean for a function on $X$ to have a pole at $x\in X$? I know what it means for an element of $k(X)$ to have a pole at $a\in \overline{k}$, that is not my question. Thanks for Your help, appreciate!

Comment: $k(X)$ is the field of rational functions, $u(X)/v(X) \in k(X)$ has a pole  of order $n$ at $a$ if the polynomial $v$ has a zero of order $m+n$ at $a$ and $u$ has a zero of order $m$. The point of $\Bbb{P}^1_k$ is to also consider the zero/pole at $\infty$, so that a polynomial of degree $d$ has a pole of order $d$ at $\infty$ (thus the same number of zeros and poles).

Comment: Thanks, I understand now what it means for $\frac{u(X)}{v(X)}$ to have a pole at $a\in \overline{k}$. But I don't understand what it means for a function $f\in k(X)$ to have a pole at $x\in \mathbb{P}_k^1$ and what it means in general for a function $f\in K_X$ to have a pole at $x\in X$. I could not find a definition of this notion, neither on the internet nor in the books that I have (e.g. Wedhorn).

Comment: I mean, points of $\mathbb{P}_k^1$ are **not** the same as elements of $\overline{k}$, right!? That still confuses me. Thanks for Your patience.

Comment: For $k$ algebraically closed, (closed)  points of $\Bbb{P}^1_k$ are the same as elements of $\overline{k} \cup \infty$ (this is the idea of affine cover of $\Bbb{P}^1_k$). For $k$ not algebraically closed we put the $Gal(\overline{k}/k)$ orbit of $a \in \overline{k}$ into the same "larger point". For varieties of larger dimension we also consider the non-closed points, for example the hypersurfaces, and we put the Zariski topology (the open/closed sets are defined by algebraic equations / or ideals of the $O_X(U)$) on those things.

Comment: Thank You for Your patience, I got it now.